# Invalid parameter estimator for estimator MLPClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When I tried to use `GridSearchCV` for `MLPClassifier`:

```py
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from numpy import logspace

X, y = make_classification(random_state=42)

mlp = MLPClassifier(solver="lbfgs", hidden_layer_sizes=(100,), random_state=1)

paramgrid = {
    "estimator__alpha": logspace(-3, 2, 20),
}
mlpcv = GridSearchCV(mlp, paramgrid, cv=5)
mlpcv.fit(X, y)

print(mlpcv.best_params_)
```

But I got this message:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter 'estimator' for estimator 
  MLPClassifier(random_state=1, solver='lbfgs').
  Valid parameters are: ['activation', 'alpha', 'batch_size', 
  'beta_1', 'beta_2', 'early_stopping', 'epsilon', 
  'hidden_layer_sizes', 'learning_rate', 'learning_rate_init', 
  'max_fun', 'max_iter', 'momentum', 'n_iter_no_change', 
  'nesterovs_momentum', 'power_t', 'random_state', 'shuffle', 'solver', 
  'tol', 'validation_fraction', 'verbose', 'warm_start'].
```

Which parameter has the mistakes?

Comment: What is the parameter `estimator__alpha` for MPLClassifier ?

Comment: Do you know how Grid Search works ?

Comment: Instead of using 'estimator__alpha', try using 'mlpclassifier__alpha' inside paramgrid. You have to use the lowercase format of the mlp classification function which in this case is MLPClassifier().

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a grid search on `paramgrid` which contains the parameter `estimator__alpha`.

However **MLPClassifier** does not have this parameter. You should change your `paramgrid`.